# C# Covariant Returns for Auto-Implemented Properties

Tags: oop, inheritance, .net-5, c#-9.0, covariant-return-types

As you know, [C# 9.0 (.Net 5) now allows Covariant Returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns). I need help applying this to a set of classes having Auto-Implemented properties.

I have two abstract classes that represent financial bank accounts and transactions. I made them abstract since I will pull data from various data sources and while the main properties will be common across all sources, each source may have additional fields I want to keep. A 1 to Many relationship exists between both classes (1 account has many transactions AND 1 transaction belongs to only 1 account).

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Transaction> Transactions { get;  set; } = new List<Transaction>();
    ...
}

public abstract class Transaction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; } // This doesn't work unless I remove set;
    ...
}
```

And here is an example of the concrete implementations

```
public class PlaidBankAccount : BankAccount
{
    public string PlaidId { get; set; }
    ...

}
public class PlaidTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string PlaidId { get; set; }
    public override PlaidBankAccount BankAccount { get; set; } // This doesn't work unless I remove set;
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is to override the base class getters and setters so that they use derived classes. For example:

If I create an instance of the concrete transaction and call the `BankAccount` getter, I want to get an instance of the derived `PlaidBankAccount` not the base `BankAccount`.

What I've found is that when I only define virtual getter in the base class and override it in the derived class, it works. But just as I add both properties {get;set;}, I get the same error as in previous C# versions:

```
error CS1715: 'PlaidTransaction.BankAccount': type must be 'BankAccount' to match overridden member 'Transaction.BankAccount'
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I can't get this to work currently. At compile time everything seems fine, but at run time, the object appears to have two "bank account" objects on it with the same name, and references that expect to receive a plaidbankaccount instead hit a null reference exception when they instead receive a null bankaccount object when referencing the property

Comment: I ended up defining as PlaidBankAccount { get {  return (PlaidBankAccount)base.BankAccount }}

Answer (score 7):

In C# 9 properties are only able to have co-variant returns when they are **readonly**, so unfortunately, no `set;` is possible.

> An overriding property declaration must specify exactly the same access modifier, type, and name as the inherited property. Beginning with C# 9.0, read-only overriding properties support covariant return types. The overridden property must be virtual, abstract, or override.

From the [Microsoft Docs - Override keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)